# LibGdx TiledMapRenderer leaves a flickering image after each render() call

Tags: libgdx

In LibGdx when I use the below code to render a tiled map the tiledMapRenderer.render() call leaves a flickering image in the black area after just one call (I tested this by rendering in the create method only) and I haven't been able to remove it. This flickering image becomes a problem when the window size changes.

```
TiledMap tiledMap;
OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer tMR;
ExtendViewport viewPort;

@Override
public void create () {
    OrthographicCamera camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 512, 512);
    viewPort = new ExtendViewport(512, 512, 512, 512, camera );
    viewPort.update(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    tiledMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("LibGdxTutorial.tmx");
    tMR = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap);
}

@Override
public void render () {
    viewPort.update(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    tMR.setView((OrthographicCamera) viewPort.getCamera());
    tMR.render();
}
```

[This is the default window you get after pressing run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRKbb.png)

[This is the window after I dragged the right side out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnjvO.png)

The map image on the right of the second photo is the full and correct one. The map image on the left is the flickering after image (it appears full because it's one frame). Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I think you need to clear the screen every frame before you start to draw the next frame.

Comment: Thank you! I found the clear method online. For those viewing with the same issue paste this at the top of your render method. `Gdx.gl.glClear( GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear the screen each frame. This happens in the render method and should be used before you start drawing.

```
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f,0f,0f,1);  // set the clear color
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);  // clear the screen with the given color.

    .. draw next frame ..
```